# Refresh when an element changes on page

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I try to scrap an element on a website and display it on localhost with Puppeteer (1). But when this element changes, I would like to refresh data without opening a new browser/page with Puppeteer and only when element changes (2).

For my example, I use www.timeanddate.com and the element is time (hours and minutes). For moment, only first part works. I don't have solution for second one.

Please find below, my code.

*app.js*

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('main.ejs');
});

server.listen(8080);

let scrape = async () => {
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    var page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/personal.html');
    await page.waitFor(300);
    //await page.click('#mpo > div > div > div > div.modal-body > div.form-submit-row > button.submit.round.modal-privacy__btn');

    var result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.getElementsByClassName('c-city__hrMin')[0].innerText;
    });

    return result;
};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    scrape().then((value) => { // it tooks time, a few seconds while page is loading.
        console.log(value);
        socket.emit('refresh', value);
    });
});
```

*main.ejs*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>What time is it?</title>
        <style>
            a {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome !</h1>

        <div id="time">loading</div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

            socket.on('refresh', function (value) {
                $('#time').html(value);
            });         
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I try Fiverr but awful experience. I hope it will better here :)

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please choose as accepted answer so it doesn't show as unanswered. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to emit event when the data changes. There are multiple ways to do that, such as,

- Try to get new data on interval
- Look for the change and emit from within browser

## Update Code Readability

I will discuss both of them. But first, lets split the code for a better usability. It's completely optional but you should do it.

```
/**
 * Scraper
 * Use this instead of scrape variable
 */
let browser, page;
const scraper = {
  async open() {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    const url = "https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/personal.html";
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor(300);
  },
  async getTime() {
    return page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector(".c-city__digitalClock").innerText; // time with seconds 5:43:22am
    });
  }
};
```

We can add other methods to this object later if we need. This is not the best format, but this will help us understand the code better at this point.

## Method 1. Set Interval

Let's modify the connection, we just need to open the page once and poll new data on some interval.

```
/**
 * Socket Connection Monitor
 */
io.sockets.on("connection", async function(socket) {
  // open the page once
  await scraper.open();

  // start the interval loop
  setInterval(async () => {

    // get the time every second
    const time = await scraper.getTime();

    // emit the updated time
    socket.emit("refresh", time);
  }, 1000); // how many millisecond we want
});
```

## Method 2. Add events to the browser itself.

This is advanced and much more complex, however very accurate.

You can add this inside `scraper` object.

```
// <-- Pass the socket so it can use it
async runEvents(socket) {
    // Create a Shadow event tracker on puppeteer
    await page.exposeFunction("emitter", (...data) => {
      socket.emit(...data)
    });
    await page.evaluate(function observeDom() {
      // expose the observer which will watch
      //More Details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
      // select the target node
      var target = document.querySelector(".c-city__digitalClock");
      // create an observer instance
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        // Do something on change
        emitter("refresh", target.innerText); // <-- trigger the event whenever there is a change
      });

      // configuration of the observer:
      var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
      // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
      observer.observe(target, config);
    });
  }
```

And then your connection will look like,

```
io.sockets.on("connection", async function(socket) {
  await scraper.open();
  await scraper.runEvents(socket); // <-- Pass the socket
});
```

How it works,

- When the socket is open,
- We open the browser and page
- We run the events.

  - We setup a custom event which will run `socket.emit` with whatever data it gets
  - We expose the custom event on the `page`.
  - We observe the dom element from then,
  - Whenever there is a little change, we trigger the custom event we made

Here is a visual difference between these two:

(I used 500ms interval and it's 60 frames per second, so the animation is not catching everything, but it's there, **link to [repo](https://github.com/entrptaher/playground-puppeteer-time.is)**.)

[image]

## Difference

The difference between setInterval and the event is, setInterval will check after certain amount of time, while the observer will continuously observe the changes and trigger whenever there is a change.

Which to choose:

- If you like simplicity, go with `setInterval` version.
- If you need precision, go with `observer` version.

Comment: Hey Abu, you really rock !

The method #1 is easy to understand and to apply without any problem.
**For method #2, I didn't succeed** :((

Can you help a little more to fix it ? The second one seems to be really awesome.

Comment: What problem did you face?

Comment: I updated the code, there was a small typo with passing the socket.

Comment: Really awesome. Thank you a lot !

I replaced "c-city__digitalClock" by "c-city__hrMin" but it works too (initial need).  But, when I start, stop and start again app.js, I have this issue : "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to add page binding with name emitter: window['emitter'] already exists!". Why ?

Comment: I was also wondering that. It is probably getting invoked multiple times for some reason.

Comment: Wow, would like to 100+ this for adding a git repo. That is above and beyond. Kudos.