# Puppeteer and express can not load new data using REST API

Tags: rest, express, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to scrape page that has contents that change periodically and use express to present data in rest api.
If I turn on headless chrome to see what is being shown in the browser, the new `data` is there, but the data is not showing up in `get()` and `http://localhost:3005/api-weather`.  The normal browser only shows the original data.

```
const express = require('express');
const server = new express();
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

server.use(morgan('combined'));
server.use(
    cors({
        allowHeaders: ['sessionId', 'Content-Type'],
        exposedHeaders: ['sessionId'],
        origin: '*',
        methods: 'GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE',
        preflightContinue: false
    })
);

const WEATHER_URL = 'https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.793588904953985&lon=-73.95738513173298';
const hazard_url2 = `file://C:/Users/xdevtran/Documents/vshome/wc_api/weather-forecast-nohazard.html`;

(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on("request", request => {
            console.log(request.url());
            request.continue();
        });


        await page.goto(hazard_url2, { timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
        hazard = {
            "HazardTitle": "stub",
            "Hazardhref": "stub"
        }

        let forecast = await page.evaluate(() => {

            try {
                let forecasts = document.querySelectorAll("#detailed-forecast-body.panel-body")[0].children;

                let weather = [];
                for (var i = 0, element; element = forecasts[i]; i++) {

                    period = element.querySelector("div.forecast-label").textContent;
                    forecast = element.querySelector("div.forecast-text").textContent;

                    weather.push(
                        {
                            period,
                            forecast
                        }
                    )
                }

                return weather;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('error in evaluate: ', err);
                res.end();
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('err.message :', err.message);
        });


        weather = forecast;

        server.get('/api-weather', (req, res) => {
            try {

                res.end(JSON.stringify(weather, null, '  '));
                console.log(weather);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('failure: ', err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
                res.end();
                return;
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('caught error :', err);
    }
    browser.close();
})();


server.listen(3005, () => {
    console.log('http://localhost:3005/api-weather');
});
```

I've tried several solutions [WaitUntil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768750/js-puppeteer-wait-for-page-load-to-complete), [WaitFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864076/refresh-when-an-element-changes-on-page), [.then](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/598) and [sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-next-line) but nothing seems to work.

I wonder if it has something to do with express get()?  I'm using `res.end()` instead of `res.send()` is because the json looks better when I use `res.end()`. I don't really know the distinction.

I'm also open to using this [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236975/how-to-reload-page-in-puppeteer) solution.  But I received errors and didn't use it.
I also tried [waitForNavigation()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084570/how-to-wait-for-event-triggered-page-reloads-with-puppeteer), but I don't know how it works, either.

Maybe I'm using the wrong search term to find the solution.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you.